# What is the most unobtrusive way to implement a custom 'beforeunload' dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, onunload

I'm talking about a styled dialog, instead of the default 'beforeunload' dialog that can't be styled.

See Facebook: 
[image: Facebook unload image]

What is the most unobtrusive way to make this? Preferrable some script that I declare once, and magically always works.

I'm think about something in the line of:

```
function showCustomDialog()
{
    [...]
}

var unfinished = true;

$('a').click(function()
{
    if ( unfinished )
    {
        window.showCustomDialog( { originalUrl: $(this).attr('href') } );
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm affraid this will break cases where i.e. a `<a>` element is used for triggering JS-behaviour, or where JavaScript triggers a window.location.href change.

Is there a better, non-obtrusive way?

**Extra note**
- They also got it working for the back button.

**Extra note** - Apparently they fall back to the default dialog when it's out of their control.

Comment: only beforeunload() can prevent accidental back button clicks. i agree it could look nicer, but the default does take the user's theme and looks like they expect. you would lose usability and functionality by customizing it.

Comment: Well, good point. I don't know *how* they do it, but they have also the back button working :)

Comment: **Brain dump:**  Facebook probably serves/loads pages different than normal webservers, allowing them to have full control over everything.  This is how some elements, like the chat bar, stay persistent while the rest of the content loads.  In order to implement this yourself, you could have all your pages load themselves through AJAX, set the content, and update the URL with `history.replaceState`.  As for the back button, they're probably using `onbeforeunload` to trigger the previous request (breadcrumbs).

Comment: They're probably using the history api and onpopstate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: ok, make my comment read "only beforeunload() can prevent accidental _home_ button clicks"...

Comment: @dandavis Apparently they have a fall back to the ugly dialog

Comment: so, getting back to the task, are you using the history API already?

Comment: not yet - i might implement it later for parts of specific pages though. But for very different pages I have a full page refresh atm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is,that you can't predict every change in the DOM,so you can just easily refresh with every mousemove-event (touch-event for smartphones etc..) like this:

```
$(document).off('mousemove').mousemove(function(){
      $('a').off('click').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

           //your dialog goes here

      });
});
```